# how to clean database after pg_dump with pg_restore with github actions

Tags: postgresql, yaml, github-actions, pg-dump, pg-restore

I would make the backup for database A, and put the backup to database B, before putting the backup into B, I would clean B with workflow in GitHub actions I try this.
but GitHub tells me that pg_restore doesn't have options
how can I clean my database B before putting my backup into B?

```
      - name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
        run: sudo echo "nameserver ****************" >> /etc/resolv.conf
      -   name: Install pg_dump
          run: sudo apt-get install postgresql-client -y
      - name: Postgres Dump Backup
        uses: tj-actions/pg-dump@v2.3
        with:
          database_url: "postgres://USER:PWD@HOST:5432/DB_A"
          path: "backups/backup.sql" 
          options: "-O" 
      - name: Postgres Backup Restore
        uses: tj-actions/pg-restore@v4.5
        with:
          database_url: "postgres://USER:PWD@HOST:5432/DB_B"
          backup_file: "backups/backup.sql"
          # clean options not working
          options: "-c"
```

Github actions saying :

```
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'options', valid inputs are ['database_url', 'backup_file']
```

So the clean doesn't work? how can I clean my DB?

Comment: Please show the error message

Comment: @rethab , i just edited my post, i have a warnning saying ``` Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'options', valid inputs are ['database_url', 'backup_file'] ```

Comment: The `options` input is only available on `main`, but not yet released with a tag. You could ask the maintainer if they want to release a new version (I see you already [opened an issue](https://github.com/tj-actions/pg-restore/issues/52)) or use the action like so `uses: tj-actions/pg-restore@main`.

Comment: @rethab , I try with `uses: tj-actions/pg-restore@main` but I have `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/psql: unrecognized option '--clean'` error

Comment: `--clean` is not a valid option for `psql`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem :

```
     - name: Postgres Dump Backup
        uses: tj-actions/pg-dump@v2.3
        with:
          database_url: "postgres://USER_NAME:PWDp@HOST:5432/DB_A"
          path: "backups/backup.sql" 
          options: "-O"
      - name: Delete  schema of DB destination
        run: psql -d "postgres://USER_NAME:PWDp@HOST:5432/DB_B" -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS schema_name CASCADE;"
      - name: Recreate schema of DB destination
        run: psql -d "postgres://USER_NAME:PWDp@HOST:5432/DB_B" -c "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name;"
      - name: Restore Backup into DB Destination
        uses: tj-actions/pg-restore@v4.5
        with:
          database_url: "postgres://USER_NAME:PWDp@HOST:5432/DB_B"
          backup_file: "backups/backup.sql"
```